# Get sub-pixel value of height or width in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, height

I am trying to get the height of an element with it's sub-pixel value.

Take this example:

```js
var small = document.getElementById('small');
var big = document.getElementById('big');
var result1 = document.getElementById('result1');

result1.innerHTML = 'Small height: ' + small.clientHeight + '; width: ' + small.clientWidth + '; ratio: ' + (small.clientWidth / small.clientHeight) + ';';

result2.innerHTML = 'Big height: ' + big.clientHeight + '; width: ' + big.clientWidth + '; ratio: ' + (big.clientWidth / big.clientHeight) + ';';
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  float: left;
}

#small {
  width: 3px;
}

div {
  float: left;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="result1"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>

<img src="https://i.imgur.com/580DosTm.jpg" id="small">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/580DosTm.jpg" id="big">
```

Basically you can see the same image in a big size and in a very small size. In the small one the width is set to 3px. The real height is 4.51562px (can be seen in Chrome developer tools). However, JavaScript rounds the number to 5px.

What I am actually behind is the ratio. As you can see the difference ends up being big:

- Small image ratio: 0.6 (3/5)
- Big image ratio: 0.6625 (212/320)

The big image ratio is the real one because the image is not resized. Is there some way to get the real values of the height, or at least something closer than a per pixel unit round?

Answer (score 3):

The closest value I can get is reading the computed CSS properties with [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) and getting the values from there:

```
parseFloat(getComputedStyle(small));
```

It gives me in Chrome:

- Small height: 4.51562
- Small ratio: 0.6643605972158861 (3/4.51562)

---

```js
var small = document.getElementById('small');
var big = document.getElementById('big');
var result1 = document.getElementById('result1');
var smallStyles = getComputedStyle(small);
var smallHeight = parseFloat(smallStyles.height);
var smallWidth = parseFloat(smallStyles.width);

result1.innerHTML = 'Small height: ' + smallHeight + '; width: ' + smallWidth + '; ratio: ' + (smallWidth / smallHeight) + ';';

result2.innerHTML = 'Big height: ' + big.clientHeight + '; width: ' + big.clientWidth + '; ratio: ' + (big.clientWidth / big.clientHeight) + ';';
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  float: left;
}

#small {
  width: 3px;
}

div {
  float: left;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="result1"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>

<img src="https://i.imgur.com/580DosTm.jpg" id="small">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/580DosTm.jpg" id="big">
```